# Ambiguity during explicit initialization of arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char a[4] = {'7','4','5'};
  for(int i=0; a[i] != '\0'; i++)
     printf("%c\n", a[i]);
}
```

Since the compiler automatically null terminates the array, the mentioned code works as expected.

But when i change line 4 to `char a[] = {'7', '4', '5'};` the code still works but prints off a few extra characters beyond the end of string.

My question is why doesn't the compiler terminate the array with a null in the second case.

Comment: Why would the compiler automatically nul-terminate the array? That's not true. It is only true if you are initializing with string literal.

Comment: In the first case as you say the `'/0'` terminator is provided by the compiler, to fill the array size to 4. But in the second case the array length is only 3, so no terminator was provided. You would have to define `char a[]="745";` to get the terminator.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler does not automatically null-terminates the array. All it does is filling in the portion that you have not initialized explicitly with zeros. In your case it's only one element that's left uninitialized, but it may be an arbitrary number of elements:

```
char a[14] = {'7', '4', '5'}; // Compiler provides 11 zeros
```

or no elements at all if you specify N initializers for an array of N elements:

```
char a[3] = {'7', '4', '5'}; // Compiler provides no zeros
```

When you let the compiler deduce the size of the array from initializers, there are no elements left to be zero-initialized, because the array has exactly three elements - `'7'`,`'4'`, and `'5'`. There's no space for `'\0'`, because it's equivalent to the situation above, when the compiler does not provide any additional zeros.

That is why if you want null termination you need to do it yourself, like this

```
char a[] = {'7', '4', '5', '\0'};
```

or let the compiler do it for you by initializing with a *string literal*, like this:

```
char a[] = "745";
```

**Note:** The compiler will provide null terminator for `char` arrays initialized with string literals only when there is sufficient space for the terminator in the array. For example, `char a[3] = "745"` would not be terminated, because there is no space for `'\0'`.

Comment: Just to add that the compiler will not add `'\0'` if the string lteral has exactly the size of the array: `char a[3] = "745";`. So for an array with given length, it does not differ if you provide a string-literal or not.

Comment: @Olaf Won't it? Or it will just overflow the array?

Comment: @Olaf Edited. Thanks!

Comment: @EugeneSh.: No, this is one of the nasty implicit things in C. Read the updated answer. Not sure if a compiler will warn about this. OTOH sometimes it is usefull (but possibly not worth the potential problems).

Answer (score 0):

You declared the first array as a 4-element array of `char`, and only explicitly initialized the first three elements.  As a result, the compiler implicitly initialized the fourth element to 0 (the compiler isn't treating the array as a *string*, though; it's just a rule that if there aren't as many initializers as there are elements in the array, the remaining elements are initialized to 0 or NULL depending on the type of the array).

You declared the second array as a 3-element array of `char` and explicitly initialized *all* of the elements (the array size is taken from the number of initializers).  There's no room for a null terminator, and the compiler doesn't extend the array to insert one.